# mysqlPDO access violation, not sure what the issue is

Tags: php, mysql

Been trying to figure this out for a while now.  No such luck.  Getting a mysqlPDO access violation on a simple form submission.  The username, pass etc are all correct and functional.

```
<?
function testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password){
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
return $dbh;
}

try { 
$dbh = testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password);
// echo 'Connected to database';
} catch(PDOException $e) {
// echo $e->getMessage();
}

$articleid=$_POST[articleid];
$published="0";
print_r($_GET); // returns empty
print_r($_POST); // returns: Array ( [username] => foobar [useremail] => test@yahoo.com [commbody] => asdf sdf [articleid] => 1) 
$sql="INSERT INTO weblog_comments (id, articleid, username, useremail, commbody, published) VALUES (:id, :articleid, :username, :useremail, :commbody, :published)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':articleid', $articleid);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
$stmt->bindParam(':useremail', $_POST['useremail']);
$stmt->bindParam(':commbody', $_POST['commbody']);
$stmt->bindParam(':published', $published);
$stmt->execute();
if (!$stmt) {
  echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
  print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
}
?>
```

I keep getting a syntax error.. not sure what is wrong with the structure of my query... the table columns and spelling are identical to the mySQL table structure

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1'

Comment: The question's unclear. See the comments I posted under Tadman's answer.

Comment: Why is there no value for this? `$id="";`

Comment: How this code can work? How you are passing `$dbname` in connection string?

Comment: I updated the question to add more info.  thanks.  i removed the $id since it is autoincrement, i added the db connect function to be seen.  no errors when connecting to db

Answer (score 1):

You're creating an `INSERT` statement but you're missing the `VALUES (...)` component:

```
INSERT INTO weblog_comments (id, articleid, ...)
  VALUES (:id, :articleid, ....)
```

Note, normally you don't insert an `id` value for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field. One will be assigned by the database automatically.

Comment: tadman what is a good way to write the ID then if auto_incremented for an INSERT statement?

Comment: You just leave it out of the list of fields. That means "use the default".

Comment: @tadman The OP made an edit http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39316476/2 which now contains `VALUES...`. Not sure if you saw that. My guess is that there's are probably one or more POST arrays that are empty. Seeing what the form looks like and how that GET array is populated, won't know for sure what's the cause for it. Then there's the unknown `testdb_connect()` custom function which we dont know what that contains, the API used to connect with, etc. The question's unclear and needs to be updated in order to know which animal(s) we're dealing with here exactly.

Comment: @tadman However, that error might be caused by the `id` parameters. If it's an AI'd column and they're trying to enter a value for it, that could proably trigger such an error. We won't know that till we know what the db schema looks like. Edit: But `$id="";` looks to be the fault... I think.

Comment: the db connection is fine, not spitting out errors  $id="" is the fault?  why do you say that?

Comment: @bobafart Inserting an invalid value into a column like that can be trouble. Just remove all references to it.